# Sharepoint Shared Services Error

Tags: sharepoint-2007, service, shared

I am biulding a sharepoint 2007 farm but whilst trying to configure the Shared Services I am getting an error of

(Provisioning failed: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: adminWebApplication)

I have tried googleing but dont seem to come up with an exact answer.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a web application that will host your ssp before you create the ssp itself. Did you create that web application. Did it get created successfully? If possible, try to recreate that web appliation. It seems to me that your ssp web app has a problem.

Also, you should provide more information. Lots of things can be 'configured' in SSP. What *exactly* are you trying to do?